# Change of variable in Bertsekas nonlinear programming chapter 1.3

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, change-of-variable, gradient-descent

I'm trying to understand how a very simple change of variables works for the following gradient descent equation.
\begin{align}
x^{k+1} = x^k - \alpha^kD^k \nabla f(x^k)
\end{align}
This is supposedly viewed as a scaled version of steepest descent and they prove it by setting:
\begin{align}
S = (D^k)^{1/2}
\end{align}
They then use this to consider the transformation of variables
\begin{align}
x = Sy
\end{align}
The minimization problem gets rewritten as
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize } h(y) \equiv f(Sy) \\
&\text{subject to } y \in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}
And finally they say they can write this as follows:
\begin{align}
y^{k+1} = y^k - \alpha^k \nabla h(y^k)
\end{align}

Where does $D^k$ go? My work so far is simply plugging in $Sy$ for $x$ and then multiplying by the inverse as follows which gets me the following:
\begin{align}
Sy^{k+1} &= Sy^k - \alpha^k D^k \nabla f(Sy^k) \\
S^{-1}(Sy^{k+1}) &= S^{-1}(Sy^k - \alpha^k D^k \nabla h(y^k)) \\
y^{k+1} &= y^k - \alpha^k S^{-1}D^k \nabla h(y^k) \\
y^{k+1} &= y^k - \alpha^k D^{-1/2}D^k \nabla h(y^k) \\
\end{align}
Where do I find my other $D^{-1/2}$ to make $D^k$ go to 1?

Edit: Here is the solution for anyone who needs it:

We need the $D = S^2$ and $\nabla h(y^k) = S\nabla f(Sy^k)$

\begin{align}
Sy^{k+1} &= Sy^k - \alpha^k S^2 \nabla f(Sy^k) \\
Sy^{k+1} &= Sy^k - \alpha^k S \nabla h(y^k) \\
S^{-1}(Sy^{k+1}) &= S^{-1}(Sy^k - \alpha^k S \nabla h(y^k)) \\
y^{k+1} &= y^k - \alpha^k \nabla h(y^k) \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the gradient of $h(y) = f(Sy)$ wrt $y$:
$\nabla_y h(y) = S^T \nabla_x f(Sy) = S \nabla_x f(Sy)$ ($S$ seems to be symmetric?)
Could be where you had a missing $S$.

Comment: That makes sense, but wouldn't that give my last step to be $y^{k+1} = y^k - \alpha^k D^{-1/2}D^k D^{1/2} \nabla h (y^k)$. But yes S is symmetric and $D = D^{1/2}D^{1/2}$

Comment: From $x^{k+1} = x^k - \alpha^kD^k \nabla f(x^k)$, we have $Sy^{k+1} = Sy^k - \alpha^k S^2 \nabla f(Sy^k)$, then $Sy^{k+1} = Sy^k - \alpha^k S \nabla_y h(y^k)$, then compose by $S^{-1}$.

Comment: Right I see now. $S^2 = D$ and since $\nabla h(y) = S'\nabla f(Sy)$ as you said in your initial comment. That clears everything up thanks for the help!